# UI being block when viewmodel method is called

Tags: android, kotlin

I'm having an issue where whenever I call this ViewModel method I got the UI blocked and the line `ui_registration_done_progressBar.visibility = View.VISIBLE` is not executed even though the debbuger shows me that is called normally

The `sendRegistration` method deals with a lot of stuff and takes some time to be finished, once it is finished the UI is unlocked and the `ui_registration_done_progressBar.visibility = View.VISIBLE` is executed

```
override fun onClick(v: View?) {
    when(v?.id){
        R.id.ui_registration_done_next ->{
            ui_registration_done_progressBar.visibility = View.VISIBLE
            sendRegistrationViewModel.sendRegistration()
        }

    }
}
```

I tried to call faster methods from ViewModel the in this case the problem does not occurs

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would recommend getting the long running task off of the UI thread. You could add use a runnable or an async task.

e.g.:

```
    Runnable runnable = new Runnable() {
         @Override
         public void run() {
             sendRegistrationViewModel.sendRegistration();
         }
    };

    AsyncTask.execute(runnable);
```

Comment: Apologize for the Java on a Kotlin question btw =D

Comment: If you need run callback after call method of modelview, you may use interfaces.

Comment: @AzraelPwnz after i add the Runnable my code got mad... Some methods (like sqlite access are not being executed anymore)

Comment: I encapsulated all the methods but the one who call my SQLite repository and everything started to work, thank you very much @AzraelPwnz

Answer (score 0):

You can use [doAsync](https://github.com/Kotlin/anko)  to run the task in a background thread

```
import org.jetbrains.anko.doAsync
...
...

    override fun onClick(v: View?) {
        when(v?.id){
            R.id.ui_registration_done_next ->{

                doAsync {
                 ui_registration_done_progressBar.visibility = View.VISIBLE
                 sendRegistrationViewModel.sendRegistration()
                }

            }

        }

}
```

adding the dependency into your `build.gradle` file:

```
dependencies {
    ...
    ...  
    //* To use doAsync instead of AsyncTask
    implementation "org.jetbrains.anko:anko-commons:0.10.4"
}
```